# Solve for x : $ \ln (x^2-x-1) > 0 $

Tags: inequality, logarithms, real-numbers

$$
\text{Solve for x }
$$
$$
 \ln (x^2-x-1) > 0
$$

Here is how I proceded

So we have to basically solve these 2 equations

By the log rules
$$
\ x^2-x-1>1
$$

And since domain of log is $(0,\infty)$

$$
x^2-x-1>0 
$$

Upon solving these two equations , the solution that I got was as follows

$$
x\in \left({-\infty},\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right) \cup \biggl(2,\infty\biggr)
$$

But the answer in textbook and even on online calculator is

$$
x\in \biggl({-\infty},1\biggr) \cup \biggl(2,\infty\biggr)
$$

Is there any mistake in how I solved the question ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $x^2-x-1>1, $ then certainly $x^2-x-1>0$

Comment: Upon solving these two inequalities, you should arrive at the desired answer. Hence you did something wrong somewhere between "Upon solving these two equations" and "the solution that I got was as follows"

Comment: You should apply $x^2-x-1>1$

Answer (score 1):

No need to make reference to the domain of $\ln$. You already had from the beginning that $$x^2-x-1>1.$$ Any value of $x$ that satisfies this inequality will satisfy the original one. So in fact, we have an equivalence.

To finish the problem, we just notice that $$\left(x-2\right)\left(x+1\right)> 0\Leftrightarrow $$ $$
x\in \left({-\infty},-1\right) \cup \left(2, \infty\right).
$$

Comment: If we take value of x somewhere between $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and ${-1}$ , then it will satisfy this equation not the original one .

Comment: It will satisfy the original equation too. That's the whole point of my argument. [Here's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28%28-1.2%29%5E2-%28-1.2%29-1%29) a numeric example, if you're still not convinced.

Comment: i get it now  . I was just confused between numbers

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
$$\ln(x^2-x-1)>0$$ 
As log is defined for values $> 0$ , $x^2-x-1$ should be $> 0$,
And as $e^x$ is an increasing function, applying $e^{f(x)}$ on both sides, gives us : $x^2-x-1>1$

Remember, we need a solution which satisfies the 1st inequality **and** 2nd inequality not **or**.
On solving, 
you would get x belongs to $$\left(-\infty,\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}, +\infty\right) $$ for 1st inequality.

And for second one , $$(-\infty,-1) \cup (2,+\infty)$$

We need the solution which satisfies the both, in set theory, **and** refers to **intersection** of sets, so our final answer is,$ (-\infty,-1) \cup (2,\infty)$

or instead by a clear examination you would notice that just by solving the 2nd inequality we would get an answer for 1st one as well, as $1>0.$

The part where you have done wrong is, either you misplaced $-1$ with $+1$ and took intersection of sets or, you have considered union of sets instead of intersection.

Hope it helps, sorry for the typos(if any).

Comment: I get it now. The mistake that I did was I was just confused between numbers while finding the intersection of these sets

Comment: Glad you have found your mistake. And thanks for the edits :)

Answer (score 0):

You need $x^{2}-x-1>1$ or $x^{2}-x-2>0$ or $(x+1)(x-2) >0$. This gives $ x>2$ or $x <-1$.

$x^{2}-x-1>1$ automatically implies $x^{2}-x-1>0$ and there is no need to worry about domain of $\log$.

Comment: If we take value of x somewhere between $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and ${-1}$ , then it will satisfy $x^2-x-1>1$ but not the $x^2-x-1>0$ .

Comment: @YADAV How can real number be greater than $1$ but not greater than  $0$?

Comment: I totally understand what you are trying to say and get that too but here I found a counter example between the solution sets of these two equations .

Comment: @YADAV $-0.9$ is between these numbers. See if $x^{2}-x-1$ is positive or negative for this value of $x$.

Comment: Oh sorry. i get it now . I had confusion in my mind about -0.6 being smaller than -1 . now it is pretty clear .

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln (x^2-x-1)>0$$
So $x^2-x-1>0 \implies x < \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $x > \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}~~~(1)$.
Next, $x^2-x-1>1 \implies x <-1$ or $x>2. ~~~(2).$ finally the overlap of (1) and (2) gives the answer as $x\in (-\infty, -1) \cup (2, \infty).$

Comment: Does overlap mean 'intersection' of these solution stes because if it means then it gives the same answer as mine .

Comment: Yes, the overlap means intersection (common domain) and this in your case ise is $(-\infty,-1) \cup (2, \infty).$ Mind -1 here.

Comment: sorry , I now get it

Comment: @YADAV That is is good,  Now You need to accept one answer.